# AWS ElasticSearch cluster is stuck on "Processing"

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I have an ElasticSearch cluster in AWS with Kibana to store logs and it has been almost a week or may be more that it has the status "Processing".
No logs are being indexed and there is nothing no tee in Kibana.
Here are some information about the cluster:

```
Instance type m3.medium.elasticsearch
Elasticsearch version 5.5
EBS volume size 100 GB
Number of instances 2
Availability zones 1
Cluster Health Status: Green
Number of nodes 4 (which is weird because there are only 2 instances)
Cluster writes status (ClusterIndexWritesBlocked) ( RED )
Snapshot failure status (AutomatedSnapshotFailure) ( RED )
Free storage space (GiB) per instance : 12 GiB
```

I obviously tried the commands in this link: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/es-domain-stuck-processing/?nc1=h_ls

but I get the error

```
{"Message":"User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpGet"}
```

Any idea how to make the cluster working again please ?

Comment: It seems that the ratio of free storage (12GB) vs total storage (100GB) is very low and you might have [crossed the threshold](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/disk-allocator.html) after which the cluster blocks all writes (=> indicated by the "Cluster writes status: RED" message).

Comment: Looks like it died during resizing. During this process a second copy of each node  is created (double the nodes). We had two clusters do this in the Sydney region